# Black reflections at extreme angles with glossy shader on smooth surfaces

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders

How do I remove them?

[image]

They don't appear when using flat shading.

[image]

Nothing in the scene can cause this.

Comment: Cycles is your render?

Comment: Glossy surfaces reflec the things around them... is your environment empty or black?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem occurs in smooth shading because it changes the way the shading is calculated across the surfaces, giving the illusion of a smooth surface even if the angle between the faces is sharp.

To correct that, add edge split modifier while all faces are set to smooth shading.

Comment: Would be useful to add *why* this is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

- Consider using a mix shader in Cycles. Mix a combo of diffuse dominantly and and gloss to a lesser degree.
- Replace your first shader with the mix shader then add the gloss and diffuse

Comment: While this does help, it doesn't remove the problem completely.