# Both Smoothing / Subdivision creates unwanted outcomes (squashing UV label or black tint in glass)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

The bottle needs either smoothing or subdivision to look right however applying either causes issues. Subdivision squashes my label and smoothing makes for a black tint on the glass. As far as the tint --I tried increasing the Transmission value in the render properties / Light Paths and the dark spots did not go away.

[image]

Comment: Solution to the subdivision label squash:  I found I can edit the UV map after adding the subdivision.  The black tint remains a mystery.

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31127/black-reflections-at-extreme-angles-with-glossy-shader-on-smooth-surfaces/31129#31129